# How to deploy qt application using Qt c++

Tags: windows, deployment, qt-creator, mingw-w64, windeployqt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxRoD.png)

I'm trying to deploy my Qt c++ project.I build it successfully and can also execute it on Qt-Creator.

However, I can't execute the binary directly in the release folder due to some shared library errors.

Then i used MINGW runtime dll (mingwm64.dll) to collect all required dll using windeployqt.exe . command line and made installer of qt project using inno setup tool & installed that application  where qt creator is installed application was run on windows 10.

But now main problem is when application installed on windows 7 where qt creator not installed and run application that time getting error "The procedure entry point CreateEvent could not be located in the dynamic linking library api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll" How to solve this problem.

How can I deploy my Qt project? Is there an another step to deploy it?

Refer attachment

I want to run qt project application on any windows7 or 10 where qt not installed.

Answer (score 0):

First when you use  windeployqt.exe, this will add all thing your  app requires,
but when I deploy my simple app  I dont have libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll so I add in

MINGW32(BUILD QT)

this is my simple app:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUzcq.png

and it work in win7 and win 10:

win7:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoG8P.png

win10:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQhWV.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).